# Jenkins fails ALL THE TIME with hudson.util.IOException2

Tags: svn, jenkins

This keeps on happening and then resolving itself randomly throughout the day, across multiple Jenkins jobs:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on http://svn.myCompanyRepo.com/path/to/project
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:189)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:132)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:738)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:899)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1414)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:671)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:580)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1676)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: [etc...]
```

Has anyone else been experiencing this and is there an easy fix? I'm getting tired of getting emails for these false errors.

Our Jenkins environment is on (unfortunately) a Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error using `svnkit`. What version of the SVN plugin are you using? When did this start happening? Can you do a checkout on your server using the Subversion URL?

Here's what I would do:

- On your *Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine*, install the Subversion command line client, if one isn't already installed.
- On that build system, disable the build that's having the error. This way, it doesn't get built on you while you're debugging what's wrong.
- Using the console, find the work directory where that job is being checked out. Try to do a checkout there yourself.
- If you can't do a checkout, but get some other error, it's possible that there's a network issue involved.
- If you can do a checkout from that server, then the problem might be the Subversion plugin version. Try to move the plugin back to the previous version of that plugin. Right now, it's at 2.2 (which works for me). The previous version I can downgrade to is 1.54.

Who is the user who runs Jenkins? I know on Windows, it can be a *service account* which makes it hard to debug these things. I usually change that to a user called "Jenkins" I can log in as. This way, I'm the same user that's running Jenkins.

See if this helps you pin down the issue.

Comment: Interesting, I'm using version 2.2 of the plugin and I continue to get this error...

Comment: Can you go into the project configuration and verify the URL is correct? Can you build the project by clicking on the build button, or do you get the same error?

Comment: Issue was introduced in the 2.0 version of the Jenkins Subversion plugin. See my answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24895577/368630). You're not the only one who has this issue.