# Jenkins Server: ignore builds that fail with hudson.util.IOException2

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm continuing to have issues with the issue I've described here: [Jenkins fails ALL THE TIME with hudson.util.IOException2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333860/jenkins-fails-all-the-time-with-hudson-util-ioexception2), and another user has described here: [Jenkins/Hudson SVN Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735761/jenkins-hudson-svn-issue)

Jenkins recently updated their SVN plugin to retry on this error 10 times; while this tends to work, it still fails on each job at least once every 2 days or so, sending emails to everybody that the build failed. All that usually needs to happen to fix the problem is re-run the build and everything works.

Is there a way (perhaps a plugin or some sort of setting) to make Jenkins completely IGNORE all build failures where the line: `hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed` is in the logs? This would make things a lot nicer for everybody and reduce the number of false alarms that a build is broken.

Comment: Can you post a link to the SVN plugin that "fixes" this issue?

Comment: @ganders I am so sorry that you have encountered this issue as well. We were able to fix it using the standard Subversion plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin Unfortunately, I can't offer much more help on this other than that we have "Check out a fresh copy" selected for the "Check out strategy" on every build now.

Comment: Yep, unfortunately, so do I....I'll ask our Admins to upgrade to 2.4 (we are on 2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [Jenkins text finder plugi](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)n to mark the build successful if you find the IOException error message.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to use this! 

I've installed that plugin, along with the Run Condition Extras Plugin, but still can't find anywhere in the job configuration or the Jenkins configuration for using this plugin.

Comment: Look in the Post Build Steps list of your job configuration and there will be an option for "Jenkins Text Finder".  Check "Also search console output" to grab the error message from the build log.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it's not in the list. :/ http://i.imgur.com/MBD5Je0.png

Comment: Sounds like the plugin didn't install successfully - check the Jenkins log.

Comment: Thanks, @gareth_bowles! I showed this to our sysadmin and he was able to get it to not cause the IOException; not sure what he did, but I'm accepting your answer anyway. :)